# Responsive rescale of background images CSS

Tags: css, image, background, responsive-design, scale

I want to build a really small responsive website with an image hover effect which I create with a css background image switch.

My problem is that everything I try to rescale the image it doesn't work. "Background-size: contain" creates a big white block under the image

css

```
#m2 {
    background-image: url('../p/test.jpg');
    height: 400px;
    margin-left: 16px;
    margin-right: 16px;
    background-size: contain;

}

#m2:hover {
   background-image: url('../p/overlay.png');
   margin-left: 16px;
   margin-right: 16px; 
}
```

html

```
<a href="s2.html"><div id="m2"></div></a>
```

Is this possible with pure CSS/HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried with:

```
background-size:cover;
```

?

That stretches the image to fit the background.

About dynamic height and width, you may want to set padding to a percentage. Like padding:20%.

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/Preben/8by1412u/

Comment: yes i tried cover to but it doesn't show an image till i define a height

Comment: That is good. I would appreciate if you set this answer as the chosen answer. Thank you @FynnCornerstone

Answer (score 0):

```
#m2 { 
  background-image: url('../p/test.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  margin-left: 16px;
  margin-right: 16px; 
}

#m2:hover {
  background-image: url('../p/overlay.png');
  margin-left: 16px;
  margin-right: 16px; 
}


<div id="m2"><a href="s2.html"><div id="m2"></a></div>
```